# Total cost number - NaN

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website and there is a shopping cart. I can put stuff in there. There is also an item counter in this basket, but there was one problem. Now I need to find the cost of items added to the cart through the console. But when you try to do this, the console returns NaN.

```js
const cartWrapper = document.querySelector('#check');

window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.hasAttribute('data-cart')) {

    const card = event.target.closest('.dlg-modal')

    //Собираем данные
    const productInfo = {
      id: card.dataset.id,
      imgSrc: card.querySelector('.gui__pizzablock').getAttribute('src'),
      title: card.querySelector('.productTitle').innerText,
      price: card.querySelector('.priceTitle').innerText,
      description: card.querySelector('.gui__description').innerText,
      counter: card.querySelector('[data-counter]').innerText,
    };


    const itemInCart = cartWrapper.querySelector(`[data-id="${productInfo.id}"]`);


    if (itemInCart) {
      alert('present')

      const counterElement = itemInCart.querySelector('[data-counter]')
      counterElement.innerHTML = parseInt(counterElement.innerHTML) + 1;
      alert('wow')

    } else {

      const cartItemHTML = `<div class="item__block">

            <div data-id="${productInfo.id}">





               <img class="img__rubb" src="${productInfo.imgSrc}">
               <p style="margin: -73px 100px">${productInfo.title}</p>
               <p class="description__rubb" style="margin: 81px 100px">${productInfo.description}</p>
               <hr class="hr__rubb">
               <p style="margin: 70px 15px"><span class="amount__price">${productInfo.price}</span>руб.</p>
               <!--               <div class="items__control" data-action="minus">-</div>-->
               <div  class="counter__rubb">
                  <div  class="counter__rubb_text">
                     <a class="minus__plus__rubb" style=" -moz-user-select: none; display: inline-flex;   font-size: 21px" data-action="minus">-</a>
                     <div style="display: inline-flex; cursor: default; -moz-user-select: none;  " data-counter>${productInfo.counter}</div>
                     <a class="minus__plus__rubb" style=" -moz-user-select: none; display: inline-flex; font-size: 21px;" data-action="plus">+</a>
                  </div>



               </div>
               <div class="buy__rubb">
               <div class="buy__rbb__boxes">
                  <p style="margin: 1% 3%; display: inline-flex">1 товар</p>
                  <p style="margin: 1% 30.5%; display: inline-flex">0&nbsp;руб.</p>
                  <hr class="hr__rubba">
                  <p style="margin: 1% 3%; font-size: 16px; display: inline-flex">Сумма заказа</p>
                  <p style="margin: 1% 22.5%; display: inline-flex">0&nbsp;руб.</p>
                  <div class="btn__rubb__podval">
                  <a href="#" class="btn__rubb">К&nbsp;оформлению&nbsp;заказа</a>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>`;
      cartWrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', cartItemHTML)


    }
    offCartStatus();
  }
})

function calcPrice() {
  const cartItems = document.querySelectorAll('.item__block')

  let totalPrice;
  cartItems.forEach(function(item) {
    const amount = item.querySelector('[data-counter]');
    const price = item.querySelector('.amount__price');

    const currentPrice = parseInt(amount.innerHTML) * parseFloat(price.innerHTML);
    totalPrice = totalPrice + currentPrice
  })
  console.log(totalPrice)
}
```

```html
<div data-id="999" id="check" class="dlg-modal dlg-modal-fade" style="background: #f3f3f3; width: 790px; height: 100%; left: 100%">
  <div class="item__block__container">
    <div data-cart-empty class="emptyContainer">
      <div class="emptyBlock">
        <img class="emptyBlock" src="notfinedCart.svg" style="">

        <h2 class="emptyBlock">Empty!</h2>
        <p class="emptyBlock"><br>Oh!!!<br>Cart empty:(<br>Select something</p>
      </div>

    </div>
```

**Note:** I open cart with popup

If you do not put everything in a variable, then there are no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the initial value of totalPrice so that you aren't trying to add with an undefined value.

`let totalPrice = 0;`

```js
function calcPrice() {
  const cartItems = document.querySelectorAll('.item__block')

  let totalPrice = 0;
  cartItems.forEach(function(item) {
    const amount = item.querySelector('[data-counter]');
    const price = item.querySelector('.amount__price');

    const currentPrice = parseInt(amount.innerHTML) * parseFloat(price.innerHTML);
    totalPrice += currentPrice;
  })
  console.log(totalPrice)
}

calcPrice();
```

```html
<div class="item__block">
  <span class="amount__price">100</span>
  <div data-counter>5</div>
</div>
<div class="item__block">
  <span class="amount__price">10</span>
  <div data-counter>3</div>
</div>
```